# slow WP_Query for non-admin user

Tags: wp-query, author

I've developed a frontend user center function(login,register,edit profile,add post,etc).Everything is fine and cool except when a user other than admin is logged in ,the homepage will be very slow in his view.

I debugged it somehow and find the culprit as below:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wiki_posts.ID
FROM wiki_posts
WHERE 1=1
AND wiki_posts.post_type = 'post'
AND (wiki_posts.post_status = 'publish'
OR wiki_posts.post_author = 4 //the current user which is not admin
AND wiki_posts.post_status = 'private')
ORDER BY wiki_posts.post_date DESC
LIMIT 0, 20
```

This query took like 60 seconds! and It only happens on my hompage which is index.php in my case and loops 20 posts.

So my question is :

1) why wordpress do this query for a non-admin user evertime he logged in and try to view the homepage?

2).what might cause this? I  pretty much sure about the loop in my index.php won't bring up this.

Answer (score 0):

ok,so I digged into wp-includes/query.php,and found this on line 3180:

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
            // Add private states that are limited to viewing by the author of a post or someone who has caps to read private states.
            $private_states = get_post_stati( array('private' => true) );
            foreach ( (array) $private_states as $state )
                $where .= current_user_can( $read_private_cap ) ? " OR $wpdb->posts.post_status = '$state'" : " OR $wpdb->posts.post_author = $user_id AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = '$state'";
        }
```

So this is the trigger and I can solve the performance problem by commenting the foreach.

But my question remains:why wordpress do this and what's the purpose?

We are talk about a huge site here (with more than 40k posts).

Comment: Instead of hacking core it would be safer to look into caching plugins, which will cache the homepage for a certain amount of time and prevent the lengthy query process for front end non-authenticated users.